# Explanation of Simple Linked List Building code

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

I am approaching to use this code for building singly linked list. I am pointing out the lines which get me bit confused .

```
struct node
{
int data;
struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;    // point 1 

void creat()
{
char ch;
 do
 {
  struct node *new_node,*current;

  new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  printf("\nEnter the data : ");
  scanf("%d",&new_node->data);  //point 2
  new_node->next=NULL;    // point 3 

  if(start==NULL)
  {
  start=new_node;   
  current=new_node;
  }
  else
  {
  current->next=new_node;
  current=new_node;
  }

 printf("\nDo you want to creat another : ");
 ch=getche();
 }while(ch!='n');
}
```

point1: What is the advantage declaring the structure node as a pointer?

point2: scanf("%d",&new_node->data);

Not getting the idea how the data is stored here to the 'data' field in context of pointer and structure?

Comment: indentation, indentation =)

Comment: do you know what pointers ARE and ARE FOR?

Comment: ["If I had to do Unix again, I'd spell `creat` with an extra 'e'"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10893/what-did-ken-thompson-mean-when-he-said-id-spell-create-with-an-e) — quoth Ken Thompson.

Comment: Beware using `scanf("%d", …)` with any 'get character' routine.  The `scanf()` leaves a newline in the input buffer to be read.  The `getche()` routine is specific to Windows and I'm not sure whether it clears the buffer and demands a new single character of input, but if it doesn't, your code will seem to misbehave, not waiting for an answer to your prompt.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Nice reminder of quote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0a) pointers only save memory addresses, the compiler relies on your declaration to determine how much memory from that address (from *ptr to *ptr + size) is considered part of the object.

0b) within the struct node, you are saving the address of the 'next' node instead of saving the values of the 'next' node. this means at any time there's only one copy of each node.

1) }*start=NULL; is a short-hand way of declaring a struct node pointer called start with initialized value NULL, which means its pointing at nothing.

2a) Declaring **pointers of type struct node** lets the compiler know that after the pointer it can expect sizeof(struct node) amount of memory behind it to be readable. Obviously you have to malloc that memory beforehand otherwise errors will occur. Finally, the "ptr->data" is equivalent to "(*ptr).data", which dereferences the pointer and then asks for the data element of the struct node.

2b) the form of

```
int x; 
scanf("%d",&x);
```

passes the &x(address of x) to the function, which reads an int and puts it AT address pointed to by &x. so &ptr->data is basically == address of data.

Answer (score 1):

**How Linked lists are different from arrays?** Consider the following points :

- An array is a static data structure. This means the length of array cannot be altered at run time. While, a linked list is a dynamic data structure.
- In an array, all the elements are kept at consecutive memory locations while in a linked list the elements (or nodes) may be kept at any location but still connected to each other.

  1. So considering the purpose of dynamic creation of linked list we do not know how many nodes user will create.

     > Therefore in this case to allocate memory dynamically, pointers are used.
     >   Using pointers will give you the memory location
     >   for your struct.
  2. The purpose of scanf() is to accept the data and store it into the memory location. Here you are accepting an interger value for your data into struct which is named as `new_node`. So assume your `new_node` is something like:

  `new_node = {int data | struct node *next}` Here you want to accept the value for your integer field `data`

  There for the scanf will store what ever value you will type into the address location of `new_node`'s data.

> Here "1" represents your new_node->data accepted and "NULL" is
>   new_node->next the pointer to next node.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

point1: What is the advantage declaring the structure node as a pointer?

You can use pointer to structure as function argument rather than structure itself so as to avoid making copy of struct. As when you pass a struct compiler makes a copy of that struct.

point2: `scanf("%d",&new_node->data);`

Arrow Operator(->) is used to access members of structures by pointer variable.
Here in above `scanf` statement `new_node` is the pointer variable which is accessing member `data` of the structure.

This operation is similar to the Dot Operator(.) where we access members of structure using ordinary structure variable.